# Can I play a downloaded game on a different account?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

My brother downloaded and bought  Minecraft on our xbox one, on his xbox account. When I go into my account, it says I need to buy it. But we are using the same xbox so shouldn't it automatically let me onto it ? Please help !!

Comment: Is he sharing his content on his console?